# Row in Power BI Table blank

Tags: reporting

I need help with an issue I am facing in Power BI. I have a table connected to multiple datasets. When I refresh, I have one column not populating any data and have not been able to figur out why this is hapenning as everything looks intact. So wondering if anyone knows any possible reasons why this is hapenning?

Thank you!!

I have looked at the source data and everything looks fine. Data is updated so I dont know why this is hapenning. I have also checked the filters but still have not found problems there.